Get all hierarchy in SQL Server
I have a table like this:



ID_employee
ID_Manager




1
1


2
1


3
1


4
2


5
3


6
5


7
5


8
5



(1 is a boss)
What I would like is a result like:



ID_employee
ID_Manager




8
5


8
3


8
1


7
5


7
3


7
1


6
5


6
3


6
1


5
3


5
1


4
2


4
1


3
1


2
1


1
1



I tried to use recursion but don't print all manager of one element, only first
this is my query:
with ManagerHierarchy AS (
    select ID_employee,
    ID_manager
    FROM HierarchyResource
    UNION ALL
    select HR.ID_employee, HR.ID_manager
    from ManagerHierarchy inner join HierarchyResource as HR on ManagerHierarchy.ID_manager= HR.ID_employee
    where HR.ID_manager!= HR.ID_employee
    )


Select ID_employee, ID_manager from ManagerHierarchy
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10);

For me the problem is my boss has ID_Manager himself.

Why are employees 1-3 not in your expected results?

Employees 1-3 are in my expected result, I wrote ecc under the table but is disappeared, sorry.
thanks you for adjust my question mate

The problem is purely your SELECT in the lower half of your UNION ALL you were returning the ID_employee from the JOINed table, not the original table. All you literally need to is change HR.ID_employee to MH.ID_employee to get the results you want:
WITH ManagerHierarchy AS (
    SELECT ID_employee,
           ID_manager
    FROM dbo.HierarchyResource HR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MH.ID_employee, HR.ID_manager
    FROM ManagerHierarchy MH
          INNER JOIN dbo.HierarchyResource HR ON MH.ID_manager = HR.ID_employee
    WHERE HR.ID_manager != HR.ID_employee)
Select ID_employee,
       ID_manager
FROM ManagerHierarchy
ORDER BY ID_employee DESC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10);


gives me error "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.", if I change MAXRECURSION 0 go but is running since 10 minute

I can't replicate your problem, @MrAlsi : db<>fiddle.
